# after update - Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After I've updated my project I get this error:

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
class Search {
    private var _username: String!
    private var _userImg: String!
    private var _userKey: String!
    private var _userRef: DatabaseReference!

    var currentUser = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "uid")

    var username: String {
        return _username <- error
    }

    var userImg: String {
        return _userImg
    }

    var userKey: String{
        return _userKey
    }

    init(username: String, userImg: String) {
        _username = username
        _userImg = userImg
    }

    init(userKey: String, postData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        _userKey = userKey

        if let username = postData["username"] as? String {
            _username = username
        }

        if let userImg = postData["userImg"] as? String {
            _userImg = userImg
        }

        _userRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(_userKey)
    }
}
```

It worked fine under Swift 3 and Firebase 3.0.2, but now, where everything is update, it crashes all the time. It's not a duplicate to any other question as it worked all before.

Comment: Why do you have those private properties? Why are they declared as implicitly unwrapped?

Comment: The error is kinda because of this *if let username = postData["username"] as? String* so what's happening is one of your postData nodes doesn't have a username node (there are other reasons) so that var is not being assigned and is therefore nil. You can use nil-coalescing to prevent the crash and assign a default in case that node is not found *let username = postData["username"] as? String ?? "NO USER NAME!"* Oh, and I second what @rmaddy said.

Comment: I know that its a dumb question, but how do I solve now "Use of unresolved identifier 'postData'"? Also, I followed an old course on YT as I'm pretty much a beginner ...

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Also, I would suggest passing the Datasnapshot to the init method instead of the two parameters. That way, you get the key and snapshot information with one parameter instead of two.

Comment: Don't post ≈40 lines of code and say you're getting an error without telling us which line number is throwing the error.

Comment: in line10 I got <-error included, I thought it would describe itself @DuncanC

Comment: I put your code "let username = postData["username"] as? String ?? "NO USER NAME!" " between Line 9 and 10... could you maybe rewrite it? I know what you mean but I don't really know if I solve it the right way, sorry for that @Jay

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I fully understand the question or what exactly is causing the crash (it's probably a missing child node) or what the use case is of the implicitly unwrapped class vars but in response to a comment, here's what I would do in Swift 4, Firebase 4

Leave your Search class as is except change the init to the following (this is shortened to provide context)

```
init(withSnap: DataSnapshot) {
    _userKey = withSnap.key
    let dict = withSnap.value as! [String: Any]
    _username = dict["username"] as? String ?? "NO USER NAME!"
    _userImg = dict["userImg"] as? String ?? "NO IMAGE"
}
```

and then the Firebase function to get a user (for example) would look like this

```
let userRef = self.ref.child("users").child("uid_0")
userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let mySearch = Search(withSnap: snapshot)
    print(mySearch.userKey, mySearch.username, mySearch.userImg)
})
```

You would need to add in the rest of the class code to assign _userRef etc.

The idea here is to provide default values to the required class properties in case one of the Firebase nodes didn't exist and results in nil. i.e. if uid_0 didn't have a Username child node your class would crash (which it is). With the code above, that property would be set to a default value.

And for thoroughness suppose a user node looks like this

```
users
  uid_0: "some string"   //the value here is a String, not a Dictionary
```

that would crash my code. To prevent that, add more error checking in the init

```
init(withSnap: DataSnapshot) {
    _userKey = withSnap.key
    if let dict = withSnap.value as? [String: Any] {
        _username = dict["username"] as? String ?? "NO USER NAME!"
        _userImg = dict["userImg"] as? String ?? "NO IMAGE"
    } else {
        _username = "No user data"
        _userImg = "No user data"
    }
}
```